# What is the last answer of the integral $\int \frac{\tan(\ln x^3)}{x}$?

Tags: integration

I have to calculate this integral.
$$\int \frac{\tan\left(\ln x^3\right)}{x}\,dx$$
These are my steps -

$$\int \frac{\tan\left(\ln x^3\right)}{x}\,dx=\int \frac{\tan\left(3\ln x\right)}{x}\,dx$$

$$\ln\left(x\right)=t\rightarrow \frac{dx}{x}=dt\rightarrow \,dx=x\,dt$$

$$\int \tan\left(3t\right)\,dt=\int \frac{\sin \left(3t\right)\,dt}{\cos \left(3t\right)}$$

$$u= \cos\left(3t\right)\rightarrow du=\left(-3\right) \sin\left(3t\right)\,dt\rightarrow dt=-\frac{du}{3 \sin \left(3t\right)}$$

$$\int -\frac{1}{3u}\,du=-\frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{u}\,du=-\frac{1}{3} \ln \left(u\right)+c=-\frac{1}{3} \ln\left( \cos\left(\ln x^3\right)\right)$$

This is my last answer?

Comment: I dont understand.

Comment: I personally don't like the $\ln x^3$ because I never know if it means $\ln(x^3)=3\ln(x)$ or if it means $(\ln x)^3 \neq 3\ln(x)$.

Comment: I edited that.
My bad.

Comment: is it $$\ln(x^3)$$ or $$(\ln(x))^3$$?

Comment: The first one - $ln(x^3)$

Answer (score 0):

You're right, but I should do it this way; substituting $\ln\left(x^3\right)$:

$$\int\frac{\tan\left(\ln\left(x^3\right)\right)}{x}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Subsitute $u=\ln\left(x^3\right)$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{3}{x}\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\frac{1}{3}\int\tan\left(u\right)\space\text{d}u=\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{\sin(u)}{\cos(u)}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Subsitute $s=\cos(u)$ and $\text{d}s=-\sin(u)\space\text{d}u$:

---

$$\frac{1}{3}\int-\frac{1}{s}\space\text{d}s=-\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{1}{s}\space\text{d}s=-\frac{\ln\left|s\right|}{3}+\text{C}=-\frac{\ln\left|\cos(u)\right|}{3}+\text{C}=-\frac{\ln\left|\cos\left(\ln\left(x^3\right)\right)\right|}{3}+\text{C}$$